# Как в php расширить один объект методами другого

Tags: php

например есть

```
$a = {
         private $test;
         public function getTest(){
             retern $this->test;
         }
      }

$b = {
         private $test2;
         public function getTest2(){
             return $this->test2;
         }
     }
}

$b->test();
```

Например

```
$b = ['test'=>2];
$b = (object)$b;
```

магия

```
$b->getTest();  
$b->runTest();
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.inheritance.php

Comment: @E_p как ты отнаследуешься от о объекта? и даже если это получится откуда у родителя появится метод=)

Comment: Вопрос не понятен. Если интересует наследование то надо это делать классами а не готовыми объектами. Если хочется менять объекты на лету то вам к http://php.net/manual/ru/book.reflection.php. Но на лету этим не надо заниматься. А вообще похоже вам надо за основы языка садиться.

Comment: Да и не забываем статические методы, которые можно вызывать не создавая объекта.

Comment: вопрос абсолютно не ясен. причем тут `(object)$b` причем тут какая-то `магия`? какая магия имеется в виду? что в итоге хочется видеть на входе и выходе?

Comment: что за псевдокод вообще?

Comment: я возможно понял..... может быть тебе надо копать в сторону трейтов. http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.traits.php  .... но это лишь догадка

Comment: @АлексейШиманский трейты работают с классами, а не с объектами, но я уже похоже нашел решение, через рефлекшен

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich ну из твоего странного описания в вопросе мало что можно понять что именно тебе нужно))

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich Just a FYI За использование reflection в коде я бы на code-review казнил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно через Reflection API:

```php
abstract class Flexible
{
    private $mergedMethods = [];

    public function mergeMethodsFromObject($obj)
    {
        $class = new ReflectionClass(get_class($obj));

        $methods = $class->getMethods();
        foreach ($methods as $method) {
            $closure = $class->getMethod($method->name)->getClosure($obj);
            $closure = $closure->bindTo($this, $this);
            $this->mergedMethods[$method->name] = $closure;
        }
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->mergedMethods)) {
            if (is_callable($this->mergedMethods[$name])) {
                $closure = $this->mergedMethods[$name];
                call_user_func_array($closure, $arguments);
            }
        }
    }
}

class Bird
{
    public function fly()
    {
        echo 'fly';
    }
}

class Fish extends Flexible
{
    public function swim()
    {
        echo 'swim';
    }
}

$bird = new Bird();
$fish = new Fish();

// Расширяем нашу рыбу методами птицы
$fish->mergeMethodsFromObject($bird);
$fish->fly(); // Выведет "fly"
```

Следует понимать, что это очень сырой «прототипный» набросок решения. Для стабилизации его придётся хорошенько проработать под множество интересных кейсов:

- перекрытие имён методов
- перенос предварительно-инициализированных свойств из одного объекта в другой
- соответственно, перекрытие имён свойств
- исключение циклических связей (один объект ссылается на другой в одном из своих методов)
- и т.д.

Думаю, тут наберётся ещё с десяток всяких интересных кейсов для дальнейшей проработки.

Ещё можно `Flexible` реализовать как трейт на тот случай, если класс уже наследуется от какого-то другого. Или вовсе сделать отдельную функцию `mergeObjects($a, $b)`, чтобы оставить классы "чистыми".

Comment: спасибо возьму на заметку